# Ubuntu wont launch on dual OS

Tags: boot, grub2

[this is the error that pops up when i try to boot into ubuntu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VyoAZ.jpg)I have a hp elitebook 8470p with windows 10 running yesterday i decided to install linux ubuntu as a dual OS i installed it by following this video https://youtu.be/-iSAyiicyQY i also instAlled easyBCD which helps me choose between OS on startup. When i choose windows 10 it opens normally but when i choose ubuntu a screen shows up stating “GRUB4DOS 0.4.5c 2014-01-17 , Mem : 631K/3031M/9184M/, End : 356539

[ Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. For the first word, TAB lists possible command completions . Anywhere else TAB lists possible completions of device/filename.]

I have searched the internet for a fix to this problem but didnt auite help i downloaded super grub2 which was successful i launched ubuntu but i still have to keep the USB in everytime i want to launch ubuntu which sucks. Sorry for my bad english btw.

---

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VyoAZ.jpg)I am afraid none if these options worked for me i went into my BIOS then into my UEFI and Legacy boot order but i didnt knew which one was windows10 or ubuntu as you can see in the picture so i didnt make any changes. As for the second option  i typed “ls” and pressed enter it said “error 14: Filesystem compatibility error. Cannot read whole file” [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEoL8.jpg)

sorry if the image links are all around the place i am new to this site i added 3 picture links hope you can find them

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOujP.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

try to change boot order from the bios making ubuntu the first choice. This should solve your problem. If the problem persists and you pc moves into grub rescue mode then follow the below steps.

On the grub terminal execute these commands:

1. `ls` :It will list all your drives and partitions, like:

   `(hd0) (hd0,msdos2) (hd0,msdos1)`
2. If Ubuntu boot partition is not known, check the disks one after another:

   `ls (hd0,msdos2)/`
3. After selecting the right partition. For example lets say (hd0,msdos2) is the right partition then execute these command on terminal:

   `set prefix=(hd0,msdos2)/boot/grub`

   `set root=(hd0,msdos2)`

   `insmod normal`

   `normal`

Now you'll be able to boot into Ubuntu. After login into Ubuntu execute the following commands on terminal:

```
sudo update-grub
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

Boot problem should be fixed after this

Comment: I am afraid none if these options worked for me i went into my BIOS then into my UEFI and Legacy boot order but i didnt knew which one was windows10 or ubuntu as you can see in the picture so i didnt make any changes. As for the second option  i typed “ls” and pressed enter it said “error 14: Filesystem compatibility error. Cannot read whole file”